# Modals Javascript Laravel

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

Un gusto, quisiera saber si alguien tiene un ejemplo de un modals que lo usen con javascript, tengo el problema que tengo un formulario que me sirve para agregar,pero cuando se usa para modificar no me ejecuta el Javascript.

He leido que es pórque solamente se ejecuta en el primer Modal que se declara.

Alguien tiene una experiencia con eso ??

```
     <td>
         <h5  class="txt-oflo"> &nbsp;</h5>
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-circle btn-sm btn-circle" 
             data-id_usuario="{{$user->id}}" data-nombre="{{$user->nombre}}" 
             data-tipo_documento="{{$user->tipo_documento}}" 
             data-num_documento="{{$user->num_documento}}" 
             data-direccion="{{$user->direccion}}" 
             data-telefono="{{$user->telefono}}" 
             data-email="{{$user->email}}" 
             data-id_rol="{{$user->idrol}}"  
             data-usuario="{{$user->usuario}}"  
             data-imagen1="{{$user->imagen}}" 
             data-id_empresa="{{$user->idempresa}}" 
             data-id_caja="{{$user->idcaja}}" 
              data-toggle="modal" 
              data-target="#abrirmodalEditar">
             <i class="ti-pencil-alt"></i> </button>
         </td>



**Modals en blade.**
<!-- ABRIL MODAL-->
<div class="modal fade" id="abrirmodal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-primary modal-xl" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                        <input type="hidden" id="id_usuario" name="id_usuario" value="">

                            <h4 class="modal-title">Agregar usuario</h4>

                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                              <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-body">


                       <form action="{{route('user.store')}}" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">                          
                    {{csrf_field()}}
                    <body onload="sucursal();">
                        @include('user.form')
                    </body>
                    </form>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <!-- /.modal-content -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
            </div>
<!-- FIN MODAL -->

<!-- ABRIL MODAL EDITAR-->
<div class="modal fade" id="abrirmodalEdit" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" 
style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-primary modal-xl" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Modificar usuario</h4>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                              <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-body">


                        <form action="{{route('user.update','test')}}" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                {{csrf_field()}}
                                <body onload="sucursal();">
                                @include('user.form')

                                </body>
                        </form>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <!-- /.modal-content -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
            </div>
    <!-- FIN MODAL -->



    /*scripts*/
     $('#abrirmodal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

        //console.log('modal abierto');
        /*el button.data es lo que está en el button de editar*/
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget)

        var nombre_modal_editar = button.data('nombre')
        var tipo_documento_modal_editar = button.data('tipo_documento')
        var num_documento_modal_editar = button.data('num_documento')
        var direccion_modal_editar = button.data('direccion')
        var telefono_modal_editar = button.data('telefono')
        var email_modal_editar = button.data('email')
        /*este id_rol_modal_editar selecciona la categoria*/
        var id_rol_modal_editar = button.data('id_rol')
        var usuario_modal_editar = button.data('usuario')
        //var password_modal_editar = button.data('password')
        var id_usuario = button.data('id_usuario')
        var id_empresa = button.data('id_empresa')
        var id_sucursal = button.data('id_sucursal')
        var id_caja = button.data('id_caja')

        var modal = $(this)
        // modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient)
        /*los # son los id que se encuentran en el formulario*/
        modal.find('.modal-body #nombre').val(nombre_modal_editar);
        modal.find('.modal-body 
      #tipo_documento').val(tipo_documento_modal_editar);
        modal.find('.modal-body 
       #num_documento').val(num_documento_modal_editar);
        modal.find('.modal-body #direccion').val(direccion_modal_editar);
       modal.find('.modal-body #telefono').val(telefono_modal_editar);
        modal.find('.modal-body #email').val(email_modal_editar);
        modal.find('.modal-body #id_rol').val(id_rol_modal_editar);
        modal.find('.modal-body #usuario').val(usuario_modal_editar);
        //modal.find('.modal-body #password').val(password_modal_editar);
        modal.find('.modal-body #id_usuario').val(id_usuario);
        modal.find('.modal-body #id_empresa').val(id_empresa);
        modal.find('.modal-body #id_sucursal').val(id_sucursal);
        modal.find('.modal-body #id_caja').val(id_caja);

        })


    /*este evento no funciona cuando se lanza el modal modificar*/
     function sucursal(){
      var Empresa = $('#id_empresa').val();
      var Suc;
        $.get('usersucursal/'+Empresa, function(data){
    //esta el la peticion get, la cual se divide en tres partes. ruta,variables 
      y funcion
       //   console.log(data);
            var old = $('#id_sucursal').data('old') != '' ? 
         $('#id_sucursal').data('old') : '';

        $('#id_sucursal').empty();
      //  $('#id_sucursal').append("<option value=''>Selecciona una 
    sucursal</option>");
          var sucursal_select; //= '<option value="">Seleccione 
     Sucursal</option>'

            for (var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
            sucursal_select+='<option value="'+data[i].id+'"' + (old == 
     data[i].id ? "selected" : "") + '>'+data[i].nombre+'</option>';

            }

            $("#id_sucursal").html(sucursal_select);
            console.log($("#id_sucursal").html(sucursal_select));
            caja();
      });

    }
```

acá esta prácticamente todo lo que uso..
Todo comentario sera bienvenido.

He leído que no me funciona porque al parecer solamente el primer modal que en este caso es de agregar, toma el código de Javascript

Comment: Cambia esa imagen por linea de codigo y tambien agrega la parte del script donde interactuas con el modal.

Comment: falta el elemento al cual clickear cuando llamas al modal. De todas formas no entiendo tu problema, tu modal no aparece, no carga los datos del elemento a editar, o no lo actualiza?

Comment: ya lo actualice, las disculpas del caso

Comment: yo te ayudo pero podrias explicar mas sobre tu flujo ya que pueden haber diferentes maneras de resolverlo.

Comment: Hola @JoséGiovannySolísNiño el problema que tengo es que al darle al evento modificar ya no me carga los datos a los select de javascript que se llenan desde el primer select donde esta el de empresa, y en el modal #abrirmodal que es el primero que esta declarado, en ese si funcionan perfectamente, ya puse un console.log en modificar y la peticion me devuelve valores pero no los asigna al select